# What is the best method to cut 'Mother of Pearl' super thin seashell tile?

Tags: tile, cutting

My wife bought this super thin seashell alike Tile called "Mother of Pearl" but I don't know the proper way to cut it. The tile seems to be very fragile and looks like it breaks into pieces easily.  I did some Google search and here are what I have found:

(1) Masking tape on a tile and cut with wet saw

(2) Nail clipper but won't be straight

(3) Dremel cutting wheel but takes forever

(4) Angle grinder with dry diamond blade with piece of wood as guide

(5) Masking tape on the hard surface and use wheel type mosaic tile cutter

Wondering how professional will do this? Anyone has good experience in cutting this? Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small tile like this I would snap it off.

First, scribe the tile with a carbide scribe line where you want it to break.

Next, use a glass cutter to make a groove along the line with the help of a square or a ruler.

Put the tile in a vise with wooden jaws or otherwise clamp it securely.

Snap off the excess with a pair of pliers.

Comment: @userb00 Would you mind upvoting the answer if you think it contains potentially useful information?